# Cause and cure of silly behavior in children

Tags: behavior, primary-schooler, speech

What can be some of the causes/reasons that a child (in the 7-year-old range) to speak in a silly voice and in a silly way, more than an average child? I don't know how to be more specific by silly voice and in a silly way, but I mean that the child speaks with a different voice, usually mimicking a spoiled 2-year-old in a way that is not the natural way that he usually speaks and it is pretty annoying and not very likable. It happens very often when the child communicates with grown ups. I am guessing it can be an attempt to draw attention or be liked more but I'm not a psychologist so I thought I'd ask.

What are some of the causes of this type of behavior in children, and what are some of the cures for it?

Comment: Cause: being a kid. Cure: time. I think I would seriously question the child psychologist that says there's something wrong with a kid being silly

Comment: Having a new baby in the house or in the larger family group can cause this as well. Some adults talk 'baby talk' to very young children. This has been the single biggest reason I've seen this sort of regression in older kids -- they are envious of the attention smaller children get.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ignore it.  Your child will most likely outgrow it if you ignore it.  It sounds like a submissive behavior -- a way to say "I'm just a little child" without saying so out loud.  You might reflect on why the child insists on telling the world "I'm very childish" in these interactions.  Something is making this child want to project the fact that he/she isn't grown up.  Are you heavily focused on "acting your age?"  That might explain it.  Is he/she stressed about growing up?  It's hard to know without seeing the bigger picture.  A family therapist could probably help if it's really that big of a problem, but I'd probably try ignoring it for a while first.

Comment: Hear hear. I ignore the insanity of my kids and it works. Sometimes if it gets to be too much I keep a lollipop in my pocket and motion that I'm looking for the trash. They straighten out as soon as they think candy is going to waste.

Answer (score -1):

- Sure seems like children are simply **allowed** to be sillier, and more often silly, than they were allowed when I was growing up -- or when my kids were growing up (I’m a 76 year old grandfather).  “Children should be seen – not heard.”
- My memory isn’t that good these days, so maybe I’m just forgetting the silliness. Does anyone agree with my assessment above?

Comment: The OP is also asking how to cure them from that behavior - can you add an answer to that question, too?

Answer (score -3):

When a child begins speaking like a much younger child, it could be a sign of regression. It can be normal if a child is under stress and wanting to go back to a time when they felt safe and cared for. However, regression can happen in response to any type of abuse they don't feel comfortable talking about. I would suggest finding a good play therapist to help uncover what is going on.

Comment: I think you're suggesting something that is a last, not a first resort.